# h2o tensorflow deep learning demo fails

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, tensorflow, jupyter, h2o

I watched the video demo
http://www.lectoro.com/index.php?action=search&ytq=H2O%20TensorFlow%20Deep%20Learning%20Demo

I am able to set up the env using the same spark and sparkling-water versions. The tensorflow runs on python3. Apparently, the example uses python2 code. I am getting SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. It points to a file with an extreme long path starting with /private ends in context.py.

Is there a way I can get this demo to work with my python3 environment?

Answer (score 1):

yes, right now demo is Python 2 specific. However, we will update it to match Python 3 syntax. I meantime feel free to modify code or look at DeepWater which introduces Deep Learning on top of MxNet (and TF, and Caffe - in progress) https://github.com/h2oai/deepwater

Comment: FYI: I reported the issue here: https://0xdata.atlassian.net/browse/SW-248

Comment: Help me out a bit. where do I find the python2 specific code to modify? I am not able to figure out looking at the notebook UI.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are using this python notebook: https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/blob/master/py/examples/notebooks/TensorFlowDeepLearning.ipynb

The changes for Python 3:

In [8] put parantheses around:

```
print( [c.dim for c in H2O_w] )
print( [c.dim for c in H2O_b] )
```

In [3] add a `list()` around the use of `range()`:

```
sc.parallelize(list(range(NODES)), NODES).map(map_fun).collect()
```

And [4]:

```
self._x = list( range(784) )
```

(I notice this change had already been done in the call to `train()`.)

I couldn't spot anything else, and those changes should be compatible with Python 2. If you still get errors can you post in which section of the notebook that the error happens in?

Comment: In the notebook that should be enough, but unfortunately we are also missing some changes in pysparkling, I should commit them today though

Comment: The version in master was updated to support Python3: https://github.com/h2oai/sparkling-water/blob/master/py/examples/notebooks/TensorFlowDeepLearning.ipynb

The change will be propagated into release branches soon.